# Асинхронная отправка http запросов

Tags: java

При асинхронной отправке запросов в цикле, т.е отправляются запросы в каком то определенном порядке, эти запросы должны дойти до получателя в том же порядке что и были отправлены или нет?

Comment: Не обязательно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ВЫ отправляете запрос асинхронно. Это говорит лишь о том что вызов метода не блокирует основной поток. А сколько по времени он будет его отправлять это совсем другое. И получать сервер будет тоже также асинхронно. Если хотите очерёдность то используйте синхронность либо отправляйте последующие запросы по получении ответа предыдущего по очереди проще говоря.

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => {
    .... // working with response
    return fetch('http://example.com/movies1.json');
  }). ....  ;
```